# Chrome download text file, not open in window

Tags: google-chrome

How can I set up a link to a text file so that Chrome will download the file instead of displaying it?

Comment: This seems like it would be not related to google chrome as much as web development in general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force download a picture from Google Chrome without opening new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632013/force-download-a-picture-from-google-chrome-without-opening-new-tab)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the build-in developer function (F12), just right-click the file as select `Save as..`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to do something similar to the answer from this very similar question

[Force download a picture from Google Chrome without opening new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632013/force-download-a-picture-from-google-chrome-without-opening-new-tab?rq=1)